# How to stop a swingworker performing one task "if it hangs"?

Tags: java, junit, timer, swingworker

I'm implementing a GUI for a JUnit test and I currently have a SwingWorker performing a set of JUnit tests.

I'm using a 3rd party program to get access to a USB device and perform the JUnit tests on that device. However I have a problem of how to stop the SwingWorker in case of no connection to the device or if the connection fails for some reason.

One simple solution would be to create a cancel button, but that is not very user friendly to just let the user wait until they get impatient and cancel the tests themselves.

Here's a sample code:

```
public void startButtonPresset(){
    class Worker extends SwingWorker<Result, Void>{
        Class<?> curtest;

        @Override
        public Result doInBackground() {

            Class<?> curtest = 3rdPartyTest.class;
            cl = com.firm.test.acp.commands.3rdPartyTest.class;
            oi = new com.firm.test.acp.commands.3rdPartyTest();

            JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
            result = junit.run(curtest);

            return result;
        }


        @Override
        public void done() {

            serialNo = cl.getField("serial").get(oi).toString().trim();
            softwareVer = cl.getField("swvers").get(oi).toString();
            testVer = cl.getField("testver").get(oi).toString();

            result = get();
            if (getOutputType().equalsIgnoreCase("console")) {
                OutputGenerator.outputConsole(result, testVer, serialNo, softwareVer);
            } else if (getOutputType().equalsIgnoreCase("csv")) {
                OutputGenerator.outputCSV(result, testVer, serialNo, softwareVer);
            }

            3rdPartyTest.setTestNamesArrayToNull();
            curtest = null;
            cl = null;
            oi = null;
            result = null;

            }
        }
    }
worker.execute();
}
```

I hope it is pretty clear that if doInBackground never returns a result the program will just hang and so goes with the interface. What I want is some way to either make a "timer" or a "partial test result" and check if some of the tests have been performed. The 3rd party tool is currently creating an array holding all the test names and I though of maybe using this, but I have no idea of how to do this together with some sort of timer.

The tests usually takes between 1 and 20 seconds at tops whether or not a link to the device has been established.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The core functionality of interrupting a test run would be the same, regardless of whether it was triggered by a button or from a timer. The key question then is: Can the test be interrupted *at all*? (It is likely possible, in the worst case it would be a bit fiddly, but I'd have to invest more time to test this (unless *you* provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ))